# LWJGL OpenGL projection matrix

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, lwjgl, projection-matrix

I am using a projection matrix that I found on the lwjgl wiki for my VBO cube.

It works fine for the most part, but when it comes to what I think is the aspect ratio, things start acting funny.

My app window resolution is 640 by 480. When I run the program this happens to the cube...

[image: Stretching Problem Image]

The face you see should be perfectly square, instead, it seems to be getting stretched with the aspect ratio.

Here is my code for the projection matrix.

```
public static Matrix4f perspective(float aspect, float fov, float near, float far) {
    Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f();

    float y_scale = coTan(degToRad(fov/2f));
    float x_scale = y_scale / aspect;
    float frustum = far-near;

    matrix.m00 = x_scale;
    matrix.m11 = y_scale;
    matrix.m22 = -((far+near)/frustum);
    matrix.m23 = -1;
    matrix.m32 = -((2 * far * near)/frustum);
    matrix.m33 = 0;

    return matrix;
}
```

Here is where I modify and translate all the matrices.

```
    Matrix4f.translate(camera.position, camera.matrix(Camera.VIEWMATRIX), 

    Matrix4f.scale(obj.scale, obj.matrix(), obj.matrix());
    Matrix4f.translate(obj.position, obj.matrix(), obj.matrix());
    Matrix4f.rotate(degToRad(obj.rotation.x), new Vector3f(1f,0f,0f), obj.matrix(), obj.matrix());
    Matrix4f.rotate(degToRad(obj.rotation.y), new Vector3f(0f,1f,0f), obj.matrix(), obj.matrix());
    Matrix4f.rotate(degToRad(obj.rotation.z), new Vector3f(0f,0f,1f), obj.matrix(), obj.matrix());
```

obj.matrix() is the modelview Matrix
obj.rotation, object.position, and object.scale are all Vector3f's
camera.matrix(*matrix type*) will either return the projection matrix or the view matrix

P.S. degToRad and coTan are methods similar to Math.toRadians and Math.tan

And here is the vertex shader.

```
#version 150 core

in vec4 in_Position;
in vec4 in_Color;
in vec2 in_TextureCoord;

uniform mat4 projection; 
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;

out vec4 pass_Color;
out vec2 pass_TextureCoord;

void main(void) {
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * in_Position;

    pass_Color = in_Color;
    pass_TextureCoord = in_TextureCoord;
}
```

Leave a comment if you need any other parts of my code.

Comment: From a quick look, your projection matrix should handle the aspect correctly. Are you sure that function is called correctly? One common mistake would be calculating aspect as `width/height` without taking into account that both of these are integers, so an integer division is carried out, only the result being converted to float when the function is called, so you'll end with 1.0 in your scenario.

Comment: So I would have to do something like this. (float)width/(float)height ?

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to be the problem and now it is fixed